# Java secure https web service and Transport Security (SSL)

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish-3, ws-security

I'm trying web sevice security with Java and Glassfish 3.1: I configured an Hello World web service to run on https listener of Glassfish (on port 8181) by setting "Transport Guarantee" of endpoint of web service to CONFIDENTIAL.

After this I edited web service Attributes and I enabled Secure Service with Transport Security (SSL) Mechanism. I'm using a trusted certificate signed by Comodo.

In web service client creation I have no errors, but when I launch my test application, I get this error:

```
%% Cached client session: [Session-1, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 320
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 32
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 1328
main, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 768
main, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 32
main, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 320
main, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 32
main, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 32
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 32
main, called closeSocket(selfInitiated)
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Invalid Security Header
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:189)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:122)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:119)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:89)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:140)
    at $Proxy43.helloWorld(Unknown Source)
    at wss_test.WSS_Test.helloWorld(WSS_Test.java:31)
    at wss_test.WSS_Test.main(WSS_Test.java:19)
Java Result: 1
```

I tried to manage urls and certificate but the result doesn't change. Which is my error? How can I resolve my issue?

Thanks in advance.

Mephysto